# How to load initial screen after an async call SwfitUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, appdelegate

In AppDelegate class I'am calling Auth API and it returns token. And then I set the token in UserDefaults.
However at this time also my HomeView is opening and its .onAppear{} function calling another api. I want to wait completion of Auth API result. After that want to open HomeView. How can I do that?

Also is this the right way for Authorization or getting token?

Here is my AppDelegate, Service, HomeView:

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        Service.shared.authorize(userName: "username", password: "password") { (response) in
            UserDefaults.standard.set(response.token, forKey: "Token")     
        } 
        return true
    }

class Service {
   func authorize(userName: String, password: String, completion: @escaping(AuthResponse>) -> ()) {
        // Here I'm calling auth api
        callApiAsync(urlRequest: urlRequest) { (apiResponse) in
            completion(apiResponse)
        }
    }
}

struct HomeView: View {
    @ObservedObject var vm = HomeViewModel()
    var body: some View {
        Text("HomeView")
        .onAppear {
            self.vm.getList() { response in
                
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can set your `window` when the Request completed

Comment: How can I? Can you give some example?

Comment: I added an answer, but you better rename your question, could be `How to load initial screen after an async call`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know where you initialize your `UIWindow`. `AppDelegate / SceneDelegate` 
My sample for the `SceneDelegate` but `AppDelegate` will be similar.

Initialize your window after the request completed.

```swift
func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
    Service.shared.authorize(userName: "username", password: "password") { (response) in
        UserDefaults.standard.set(response.token, forKey: "Token")     
        if let windowScene = scene as? UIWindowScene {
            let window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
            window.rootViewController = UIHostingController(rootView: HomeView())
            self.window = window
            window.makeKeyAndVisible()
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: Thanks Enes. Do you know for getting token by that way is preferred method?

Comment: Getting token is actually related with the backend you communicate with, but if you meant storing token, generally a more specific helper class preferred like `Session/UserSession` in the project I recently worked for.